# Flex: cannot programmatically set backgroundColor style in only some controls

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Is there some special trick to setting the `backgroundColor` style for an `mx:DataGridColumn` in ActionScript? When I try to set it programmatically (using a routine that works fine for other controls) it doesn't work. But when I set it right in the MXML tag, it works fine.

Here's my CSS:

```
HBox
{
}

VBox
{
}

Box
{
}

DataGridColumn
{
    /* background-color: #E01080; */
}

DataGrid {
    roll-over-color:#CCCCCC;
    vertical-scroll-bar-style-name:fseVerticalScrollBar;
    horizontal-scroll-bar-style-name:fseVerticalScrollBar;
    verticalGridLines: false;
    horizontalGridLines: false;
    border-thickness:0;
    backgroundAlpha: 1;
}
```

Note that I sometimes uncomment that comment--it doesn't change anything.

And the AS that should work:

```
        const arrsBackgroundTypesToSet:Array = ["HBox", "VBox", "Box", "DataGridColumn"];
        for each (var sTagType:String in arrsBackgroundTypesToSet)
            SetCSSStyle(sTagType, "backgroundColor", 0xE01080);
```

...

```
    private static function SetCSSStyle(sCSSName:String, sStyleName:String, data:*):void {
        var css:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration(sCSSName);
        if (css == null) trace("You just tried to set the style " + sCSSName + '/' + sStyleName + " but it couldn't be found");
        else css.setStyle(sStyleName, data);
    }
```

As you can see, I'm setting the `backgroundColor` in other things and it works out rather well. But not for the `mx:DataGridColumn`. Why?

Here's an example of a grid where direct setting of the style causes a style change, but the programmatic change doesn't:

```
        <UBIC:ubiDataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{objDGData}" width="100%" height="100%" sortableColumns="true"
                                    itemClick="DoClearForm();UserRemote.DoFetch(dg.selectedItem.user_id);"><UBIC:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="User Name" dataField="{StringGlobals.COL_USER_NAME}" backgroundColor="#E01080"
                                sortCompareFunction="{function(o0:VOUser, o1:VOUser):int {return UserSort(o0, o1);}}" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Printer" dataField="printer"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="CSV Delimiter" dataField="delimiter"/>
        </UBIC:columns></UBIC:ubiDataGrid>
```

That "User Name" column appears in that unmistakeable, horrid fuchsia(?) but the others don't.

And the `ubiDataGrid`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:DataGrid    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            headerColors="{[BrandGlobals.COLOUR_DARK, BrandGlobals.COLOUR_LIGHT]}" selectionColor="{BrandGlobals.COLOUR_SELECTION}"
            headerStyleName="brandedheaderstyle" iconColor="{BrandGlobals.COLOUR_TEXT_AGAINST_DARK}"
            >
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
    import mx.events.DataGridEvent;

    /*[Bindable] */public var m_nAccumulatedWidth:Number = 0;
    private var m_oWidths:Array = new Array;

    public var m_fAdjustableColumnWidthMultiplicity:Number = 1;

    public function SetSortColumn(iColumn:Number):void {
        dispatchEvent(new DataGridEvent(DataGridEvent.HEADER_RELEASE, false, true, iColumn, null, 0, null, null, 0));
    }

    protected function SetWidthToSaneNumber(oCol:DataGridColumn, nWidth:Number):void {
        const nConcreteWidth:Number = nWidth*m_fAdjustableColumnWidthMultiplicity;
        if (nWidth > 0)
            oCol.width = nConcreteWidth;
        m_nAccumulatedWidth += nConcreteWidth;
    }
]]></mx:Script>
<mx:Style>
    .brandedheaderstyle {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</mx:Style>
```

Oh, and here's something else I found very interesting. Another (and possibly better) solution would be to zero the alpha on the `DataGrid`'s background. The `Canvas` that the grid is on is the colour I want, so if I

```
SetCSSStyle("DataGrid", "backgroundAlpha", 0.0);
```

that actually *works*! It didn't work w/`backgroundColor` but it works w/`backgroundAlpha`. However, I still have the problem of the striping of the rows: they are lost. I need the rows to be striped.

I'm using the Flex 3.5 SDK.

Comment: You don't show the code for your actual `DataGrid` so this is just a guess:
Does it work when you set the backgroundCOlor in the CSS? If that is the case, maybe using your method has a timing Problem, where the change in StyleManager is not recognized by the instance(s) of the component so the are not redrawn. Or maybe the itemRenderer you are using has its own color which hides the one you set for the columns?

Comment: @karfau Definitely not a timing problem, since grids created well into the session remain unaffected. Now as for your `itemRenderer` challenge: it doesn't seem to be that, but I have noticed that the striped rows (alternating between white and grey) lose their stripes in the fuchsia(?)-coloured column. That might be a clue as to what's wrong. BTW, I'll need those stripes, too, so that's another problem. As for your other concerns, I've edited the question to reflect them.